# Contextual tokens in ANTLR?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, antlr, token, tokenize

I am trying to integrate a language into NetBeans using ANTLR, and in order to highlight syntax this involves generating tokens for every type of text I want highlighted.

Is there a way to create tokens for contextual words?  That is, suppose I want to highlight all Strings that come after "function":

```
function foo
```

where "foo" gets highlighted.

how might I define the token rule:

```
FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER
    :    //match anything after "function"
```

so that the token matches what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by overriding the `emit()` method from the lexer and keep track of the last emitted token. Then inside your `IDENTIFIER` rule, you check if the last token was a `FUNCTION`, in which case you set a different `$type` for said token.

A demo:

```
grammar T;

tokens {
  FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER;
}

@lexer::members {

  private Token last = null;

  @Override
  public Token emit() {
    last = super.emit();
    return last;
  }
}

parse
  :  (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-20s -> '\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
  ;

FUNCTION
  :  'function'
  ;

IDENTIFIER
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+ 
     {
       if(last != null && last.getType() == FUNCTION) $type=FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER;
     }
  ;

SPACE
  :  ' ' {skip();}
  ;
```

And if you run this class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("a function b c"));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

you will see:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
IDENTIFIER           -> 'a'
FUNCTION             -> 'function'
FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER  -> 'b'
IDENTIFIER           -> 'c'
```

### EDIT

Note that if you have tokens written to the `HIDDEN` channel, you'll need to change the contents of `emit()` slightly. Something like this (untested!):

```
@lexer::members {

  private Token last = null;

  @Override
  public Token emit() {
    Token temp = super.emit();
    if(temp.getType() != HIDDEN) {
      last = temp;
    }
    return temp;
  }
}
```

### EDIT II

> will this break other rules that I had? Suppose I had a rule that took all IDENTIFIER tokens and I added this contextual token. Would the rule I previously had now ignore all FUNCTION_IDENTIFIERS, causing me to have to explicitly catch both FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER and IDENTIFIER in that rule?

Yes, any rule referencing `IDENTIFIER` will **not** match a `FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER` token. If you want that, simply create a production (parser rule) like this:

```
identifier
  :  IDENTIFIER
  |  FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER
  ;
```

and replace all `IDENTIFIER` usages in parser rules by `identifier` instead.

Comment: Why do you have that extra override function in the members?  Is it because there is no way to see the emitted token without passing over it?  And the followup question: is there any way to look AHEAD and emit based on the next token?

Comment: @donnyton, _"Why do you have that extra override function in the members? Is it because there is no way to see the emitted token without passing over it?"_, the lexer emits the tokens but does not keep track of them. That is why I override the `emit()` method to keep track of the last token that was created.

Comment: @donnyton, _"And the followup question: is there any way to look AHEAD and emit based on the next token?"_, no, not from within lexer rules. The lexer operates on a stream of characters and emits tokens. So you can only look ahead one or more single characters, not tokens.

Comment: @donnyton, although you cannot just look ahead for tokens inside lexer rules, chances are something else is possible that solves your problem: you only need to explain the problem (perhaps in a new question).

Comment: @Bart will this break other rules that I had?  Suppose I had a rule that took all IDENTIFIER tokens and I added this contextual token.  Would the rule I previously had now ignore all FUNCTION_IDENTIFIERS, causing me to have to explicitly catch both FUNCTION_IDENTIFIER and IDENTIFIER in that rule?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm afraid Ultimately there's bigger issues getting this to work for syntax highlighting.  In particular, if I open a file it parses and highlights it properly, but it will not recognize contextual tokens as I type because "last" does not identify the previous token properly.  I think I am running into the barriers of formal language and not ANTLR at this point.